# Relatively good javascript security mechanism for sending data to a server

Tags: javascript, php, security

I am developing an javascript based game with a global high score ranking.

Let's assume that if I will obfucate the js code no one will have enough will to decrypt it in such manner that will allow him to do any change in game mechanics. So let's say that I don't have to bother about any in game cheating.

My question is, what can I do to relatively safely send the high score to my server using ajax? If I will put the high score into post variable then this request can be easily  faked. Any ideas how to secure it?

I know that no solution here can be threated as really safe and unbreakable, but considering that there is no additional risk if someone will break it I just need something that will be as much time consuming for a person that will try as it can be.

Comment: Do not assume the second paragraph...

Comment: Lets play unobfuscate your code! Doing that is not secure and normally takes <30 seconds to break. There really is no "secure" way to do it.

Comment: Store it as a value in an SSL cookie. ALthough , with the game running clientside in javascript highscore manipulation is the least of your worries ifyou are going down the road of security.

Comment: You should never view any "security measures" in JS as actual security . . . think of them as roadblocks to slow down/deter the person who wants to hack your code.

Comment: Guys, don't you see that I know there is no really secure client side solution. I just need something that will discourage potential cheater. This is not a banking system, if someone will breake it - so be it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No form of encryption/hashing/obfuscating will help you in scenarios like yours.
Why? Your code runs in a browser on the user's computer. That means something under the user's control (even if he is unaware of it) has access to the original data and can reproduce "legitimate" communication (and you can run obfuscated code without deobfuscating it).

The only way of ensuring your players cannot cheat is if you handle score calculations server-side, and to do that you have to send user input to the server and respond with an "OK, legal action" or "CHEATER CHEATER!!!" every time. So basically the game runs on the server with the browser only acting as a very very thin client. That's how most multiplayer online games work these days.

What I'd do is compromise a bit.
Run the game in the browser but log all player actions on the server. It does not need to be real-time.
Then write a server-side service that makes common-sense checks on this logged data and approves or rejects the final score.
Let's imagine a game of checkers. A log entry would be "move piece from A1 to B2". That's a legitimate move. Now you'd expect the other player to make a move. After that you'd see "move piece from B2 to G7". That's a clear violation and you reject the score and maybe IP-ban that player :)

If it's a reaction game you can check time/distance between moves.

Comment: I do not need to be ensured that they wont cheat. I just want to make cheating a little bit harder. If someone will break it - so be it, but I want to make this task a little tough. Also - I considered client-server architecture, but it's not worth it in this case - too much development, too many potential problems..

Comment: See my edited answer. Depending on the game mechanics it may not be that hard to implement.

Comment: This is close, but still - how to send the moves list without risking that it's fabricated?

Comment: Well, they won't be able to fabricate something that's "inhuman". It's as close as you'll ever get, and if someone has enough reason to fabricate data that looks "human" then this will be your smallest problem. As you've said, most users won't get past the obfuscated code or open up Developer Tools and fake a request. Out of those who do get past it, maybe less will dedicate enough time to understand your validation algorithms.

Comment: Also, if your game has a steep-ish learning curve you could use statistics applied to those logs. But this depends too much on the game mechanics.